# How to get a Text's shadow color programatically in android?

Tags: java, android, colors, android-edittext, shadow

I know how to set shadow for an editText in android:

```
editText.setShadowLayer(float radius, float dx, float dy, int color);
```

But my question is : How to get a Text's shadow color programatically in android?

*

> **Of course I have to add that my minimum API level is 15.**

*

Thanks to everybody who can answer this question

Comment: Post some code. How did you set the shadow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following method for **API level >= 16**:

```
int shadowColor = editText.getShadowColor();
```

For **API level < 16**, there seem to be no direct way to get the shadow color of an `EditText`.

What i would do in this case:

Extend `EditText`, override `setShadowLayer()` and write your own method to get the shadow color:

```
public class CustomEditText extends EditText {
    int shadowColor = 0;

    public CustomEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void setShadowLayer(float radius, float dx, float dy, int color) {
        shadowColor = color;
        super.setShadowLayer(radius, dx, dy, color);
    }

    public int getShadowLayerColor() {
        return shadowColor;
    }
}
```

Then use `CustomEditText` instead of `EditText` in your code/layout and call `getShadowLayerColor()` to get the color of the shadow.